# Why prestashop is not work properly with ssh?

Tags: ssl, nginx, prestashop-1.6

So i have problem with prestashop 1.6, when using ssl.If i check in SSL ENABLED, but don't check SSL ENABLED EVERYWHERE i have problem - a message too many redirect. If i check both paremeters - it's ok, all work good. My configuration: Nginx + php-fpm 
it,s my config:

```
server {
   ### Ports
   listen 80;
   listen 443 ssl;

   ###SSL PART
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/server.key;
   ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:40m;
   ssl_session_timeout 10m;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";

   #ssl_stapling on;
   #ssl_stapling_verify on;
   #resolver 156.154.70.1 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
   #resolver_timeout 10s;


   ###Headers
   add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";
   add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000";
   add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
   add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

   ###LOGS
   access_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log;
   error_log   /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log;

   ###Charset
   charset utf-8;

   ###BASIC
   server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
   root /var/www/html;
   index index.php index.html;

   ###REWRITE
   rewrite ^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;

   rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.jpg$ /img/c/$1.jpg last;
   rewrite ^/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;

   rewrite ^/order$ /index.php?controller=order last;
   if (!-e $request_filename){
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
   }

   # Redirect needed to "hide" index.php
   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
   }

   ###Cache
   location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
   }

   location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
   }

   # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
   location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
   }


   location ~* \.(gif)$ {
      expires 2592000s;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
   }
   location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg)$ {
      expires 2592000s;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
   }
   location ~* \.(png)$ {
      expires 2592000s;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
   }
   location ~* \.(css)$ {
      expires 604800s;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
   }
   location ~* \.(js|jsonp)$ {
      expires 604800s;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
   }
   location ~* \.(js)$ {
      expires 604800s;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
   }
   location ~* \.(ico)$ {
      expires 31536000s;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
   }

   location ~* \.(?:ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
      add_h`enter code here`eader Cache-Control "public";
   }  

   location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass php;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Try changing**

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

**to**

```
listen  443 default ssl;
```

I sort of remember that the "default" word was needed in my config

**Also very important is the buffer size parameters**
I have found the following config to work. The site was randomly getting a "bad gateway" response and you need to allow more buffer size and timeout.
Prestashop is sending a lot of stuff in requests and it makes nginx to fail with the default config. It is a shame that this is not documented in the official prestashop config.

```
fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```